# How do I get the result from my sql query on my text box?

Tags: ms-access, textbox, ms-access-2007

Using Access 2007, I created a form (f_login) and a query (c_login), and I want to get the result from my sql query and display on my form, via text box..
Here is my sql query (working) :

```
SELECT t_lvl.nr_lvl
FROM t_admin INNER JOIN t_lvl ON t_admin.nr_rf = t_lvl.nr_rf
WHERE (((t_admin.nr_rf)=[Forms]![f_login]![txb_user].[VALUE]) AND ((t_admin.psw)=[Forms]![f_login]![txb_psw].[VALUE]));
```

And I tried to put on my control source of my text box those codes, but none of them worked...

```
=DLookup("[nr_lvl]","[c_login]")
=DLookup("nr_lvl","c_login")
=DLookup("c_login","nr_lvl")
=DLookUp("[c_login]";"[nr_lvl] =" & [Forms]![f_login]![txb_lvl])
```

I really don't know why it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test your `DLookup` expression in the Immediate window (you can go there with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>).

See what you get after typing this in the Immediate window and pressing <kbd>Return</kbd>.

```vb
Debug.Print TypeName(DLookup("nr_lvl","c_login")), DLookup("nr_lvl","c_login")
```

You told us `c_login` is a query, showed us the SQL for that query, and confirmed the query returns the correct result.  Since `nr_lvl` is a field returned from that query, I don't see why the `DLookup` would fail when the form, `f_login`, is open in Form View.

So see what happens with that `DLookup` in the Immediate window ... whether it returns no value, the wrong value, or an error message.  Then you'll need to figure out how to change it to get the correct result.

OTOH, if `DLookup` gives you the correct result in the Immediate window, and the issue with the form is that the text box value doesn't update in response to changes in `txb_user` and/or `txb_psw` you should requery the third text box (the one which uses `DLookup` as its control source) from the after update events of those first two.